# Animating a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, tabcontrol, eventtrigger

I'm trying to achieve a nice animation while switching tabs in the TabControl.
At this point, my style animation xaml looks like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SelectionChanged">
    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="selectionChangedBeginStoryboard">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="borderScale"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX">
                <DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.2"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0.4"/>
                </DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

What I want to achieve is a rotating effect on the tab transmition. So it would look like the screen is turning away, and returns with the new tab page.

The problem is that when I switch to another tab,
The content is switched right away, and the animation is just rotating the new tab page.

Any Ideas, please? :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use a transition library, such as 'Transitionals'. You can download this library from the [Transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/) page on CodePlex.

The reason why I say this is because in order to do what you want to do, you will need to capture the `Visual` of the old `TabItem` *before* you switch tabs, animate that instead of the `TabItem` and then remove that and restore the actual controls.

However, the aforementioned library already does this and provides a number of different transitions for you to use. You can get help with using the library by downloading the 'TransitionalsHelp_1_0.zip' file from the following link:

http://transitionals.codeplex.com/releases/view/12954

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using third party programs, i recommend Blend. 
Open your Solution there and work with the `VisualStateManager`. I did a transitional effect from `Unselected` to `Selected` in less than 30 seconds. It was simple (Opacity change), but Blend is very user friendly and you can integrate with Visual Studio natively.

Here's what it generated to be (**not what you are asking**):

```
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates"/>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="templateRoot">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.8"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Good luck.